# IPA file installation issues

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am getting two app icon on iPad. When i am installing form web url.I am getting another app icon on iPad instead of updating it create another app icon. why it happen or how can i resolve this issue please let me know as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This can happen if both your applications are using different-different Bundle Identifier. Which means the version which is on web url is using different Bundle Identifier and currently you are using different Bundle Identifier.
2. There's nothing wrong in that. Hence, your device is treating them as two different Apps. And not replacing the old one.
3. Just delete both the application and download it again.

Comment: hi rushi I also check this it is fine but still that issues come on installation. Please let me know if any another ways.

Comment: @IOSDeve.ttb Did you confirm both the build are using same Bundle Identifier?

Comment: @Rushi yes bundle identifier is same in both build

Comment: @IOSDeve.ttb This is strange if your bundle identifier's are same it should not happen. You can try one more thing, delete the bundle identifier from your device in Settings. And then try to download the app again.

Comment: @Rushi  ok thanks for that let me do this process once it is done then i will let you know otherwise i will disturb you once again.